# SQL Select from 2 tables and Group by month

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Okay so I've got 2 table's

First one is called `msg` and the other one is `msg_t`

`msg` (id, send_type, ..)
`msg_t` (id, msg_id, send_time)

What I am trying to do is to get all of the `msg` rows where send_type = 1

and to count the `msg_t` entries for each `msg` and group it by month

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID, MONTHNAME(b.send_time), COUNT(b.msg_id) totalCount
FROM    msg a
        LEFT JOIN msg_t b
            ON a.ID = b.msg_id
WHERE   a.send_type = 1
GROUP   BY a.ID, MONTH(b.send_time)
```

- [MONTHNAME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)
- [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

by using `LEFT JOIN`, a value of zero will be displayed for `msg.ID` that have no records on table `msg_t`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  MONTH(send_time)
  COUNT(t.*)
FROM msg m
INNER JOIN msg_t t ON m.id = t.msg_id
WHERE m.send_type = 1
GROUP BY m.id,
         MONTH(send_time)
```